# Wordpress - How to show different post query based on current post's category

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to show a different post query depending on what category the current post is filed under.

There are about 7 or 8 categories, each needing their own little query.

Here is my current query code

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=offers&category_name=home-page&posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand'); ?>
```

All that needs to change in each is the **category_name** varialble.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been tearing my hair out over this one.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

if (in_category('Fruit')) {
  $category_name = 'fruit';
} else if (in_category('Vegetables')) {
  $category_name = 'vegetables';
} //etc

query_posts( "post_type=offers&category_name=$category_name&posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand"); 

?>
```

Comment: You're probably missing a curly brace somewhere in your code. That's not a problem with what I gave you. According to your website, you're a web developer, finding and fixing syntax errors should be like fixing spelling to you. You've also written the code for this question before, testing what category a post is in to do something conditionally happens several times in your code samples.

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired, I just don't know why you're here when it seems like you are more than capable of writing this on your own. I also changed the single quotes to double quotes in the answer.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I cut one out by mistake. Sorry, I didn't mean to seem like I was questioning your code.

Looking at it now, I can see I've done it a thousand times before. I guess you're not the only one that's tired, maybe I should call it a night / morning